# How to get next paragraph element to float around prepended image?

Tags: html, css

I have an image prepended to a paragraph element (see photo below)

[image: Floated Image]

The CSS float property for the image is set to right.

The paragraphs and image are part of a div with bootstrap class "container" so the basic layout is just

```
<div class="container">
 <img class="img-fluid">
 <p>Text</p>
 <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

However, I really hate the big, ugly white space next to the image.  How can I get the next paragraph element to fill that space?

The styling on each element is as follows

```
p {
 text-align: justify;
 text-justify: auto;
}

img {
    height: auto;
}
```

Tried CSS clear:both on divs that wrap the image and paragraphs.

Comment: You haven't told us what's the expected behavior. Do you want a column-like layout, where the paragraphs always stay in the left column or you want them to expand as soon as the image ends?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach to fill the white space next to the floated image:

Wrap the image and the text in a separate div container, like this:

```css
.image-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-text">
    <img class="img-fluid">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

The display: flex property makes the .image-text container a flex container. The align-items: center property aligns the child elements (the image and the text) vertically.

The flex-shrink: 0 property on the image makes sure that the image will not shrink to fit the available space. The flex-grow: 1 property on the text causes the text to take up all the available space in the container.

This way, the text will automatically fill the white space next to the image, without having to use the clear property.